# Read Map entity in JAX-RS client

Tags: java, rest

I have a webservice which returns a "Map", I am trying to read this object from the Response(javax.ws.rs.core).
something like this:
ex :  `Map<String, Object> temp = response.readEntity(Map.class)`
but this doesn't seem to work.

My question is how do I read a Map entity from a response object?

Comment: Reading a Map entity did not cause the IllegalStateException.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For me the error was org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1, type=interface java.util.Map, genericType=interface java.util.Map.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a way to read the Map entity from response.I guess I needed to provide the implementation class for Map.

`response.readEntity(new GenericType<HashMap<String, Object>>() { });`

Comment: This works with Jersey but does not work with Apache CXF (TomEE) where I get `org.apache.johnzon.mapper.MapperException: ObjectConverters are only supported for Classes not Types`. This works with CXF:  `client.get(HashMap.class)` and probably also `response.readEntity(HashMap.class) `